# "init terminating in do_boot" error message, when starting Yaws on Windows

Tags: windows, yaws

I would like to develop a web application in Erlang, so I installed Yaws 1.92 on Windows 7.

But when I try to start Yaws with both `yaws` and `yaws -i` I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Jonas>yaws
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{yaws,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,s
tart_em,1}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

C:\Users\Jonas>
```

Is there anything I'm missing? How can I solve this?

---

With the help from Steve's suggestion, I realised that my Erlang runtime was too old. I upgraded from R14B to R15B. Now Yaws starts, but it still prints some erros on startup:

```
C:\Users\Jonas>yaws
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1>
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:13 ===
Yaws: Using config file C:\Program Files (x86)\Yaws-1.92\yaws.conf
1>
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:13 ===
'auth_log' global variable is deprecated and ignored. it is now a per-server var
iable1>
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:13 ===
Reading .yaws_auth c:/Program Files (x86)/Yaws-1.92/www/authtest/auth_in_dot_yaw
s_auth/abc/.yaws_auth
1>
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:13 ===
Cannot open "c:/Program Files (x86)/Yaws-1.92/logs/localhost.8080.auth"1>
=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:13 ===
Cannot open "c:/Program Files (x86)/Yaws-1.92/logs/localhost.8080.access"1>
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:14 ===
Ctlfile : c:/Users/Jonas/AppData/Local/Temp/yaws/default/CTL
1>
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Feb-2012::16:22:14 ===
Yaws: Listening to 0.0.0.0:8080 for <1> virtual servers:
 - http://localhost:8080 under c:/Program Files (x86)/Yaws-1.92/www
1>
```

Any suggestion on why I get so many errors? and how to solve them?

Comment: If you edit your yaws.conf file you can move the auth_log variable from the global space into your server settings. That will fix the first error. As for the two other error reports, make sure the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Yaws-1.92\logs exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `undef` there is saying that the function `yaws:start/0` isn't found. Seems like it may be a problem with the load path.

Try starting yaws like this:

```
yaws -i -erlarg "-boot start_sasl"
```

Hopefully that will give you more verbose output to help you track down the problem.

Comment: I get: `beam/beam_load.c(1351): Error loading module yaws:
  use of opcode 153; this emulator supports only up to 152` Does that mean that I have to upgrade my Erlang runtime? I guess so. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, after upgrade from Erlang R14B to R15B, Yaws works, but I get many errors on startup, see my update.